# How to detect a web-content modification instantly using Python?

Tags: python, web

Based on Python, I want to know the **fastest way to identify a change in the content of a webpage**.

Actually and my current option is using *web scraping*; requesting the url every 1 second and fetch the result to identify the changes. However, I think it can be improved because the web server can have API throttling/limitation and it could block the IP address.

Additionally, I would like to get the change in milliseconds (instantly).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could look into headers like Last-modified (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) or ETag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) and use an HEAD request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) instead of GET. However this doesn't lower the amount of requests needed (but makes the requests way smaller).

Comment: if server doesn't use any header to inform about changes OR it doesn't have function to get only date of last modification then you have to read all again and again and compare data.